# class functions as pointers

Tags: c++, class, pointers, inheritance

These are my class functions for the header file :

```
public:
    hunter(string aSpecies);         // create a hunter of the given species
    void recordKills(string kill);   // add a new kill to the end of the hunter's list of kills
    string *theKills();              // return a pointer to the array of all kills by this hunter
    int numberOfKills();             // how many kills have been recorded
```

and class variables:

```
private:
    string kill;
    int numberkilled;
    string kills[20];
```

I am not sure on how to handle "string *theKills()"

I have tried doing it in this way:

```
string hunter::*theKills(){
    pointer = kills;
    return pointer;
}
```

as with the * it doesn't recognise `kills` as a part of my class variable, but we are supposed to use the same function names.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `string* hunter::theKills(){`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax goes as follows:

```
<return type> <class name>::<function name>(<parameters>);
```

which in your case is:

- `<return type>` is `string *`
- `<class name>` is `hunter`
- `<function name>` is `theKills`
- `<parameters>` : none

```
string * hunter::theKills() {
    return kills; // you don't need a temporary pointer variable
}
```

Saving you the trouble of using pointers, I'd advise you to use a [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of your C array `string kills[20]`:

```
std::array<std::string, 20> kills;
```

Remember to add `const` qualifier to every member function which doesn't modify any member of your class.

I'm guessing the use of `using namespace std;` which is [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: what is the difference between the std::array and C array.


also thank you for your help with the syntax your a champ

Comment: thanks heaps mate, i know it seems small, but your help is vastly appreciated!